# Setting dataType JSON in aws-sdk for sqs

Tags: javascript, json, aws-sdk

Im just trying to send a json object to sqs queue by using aws-sdk npm package.

```
const sqsMessage = {
    MessageAttributes: {
        "data": {
            DataType: "String",
            StringValue: payload.data
        }

    },
    MessageBody: JSON.stringify(payload),
    QueueUrl: queueUrl
```

If i pass json object in data attribute it tells it expected String, if i add Json then it also throws an error about type, does anyone know a workaround or what to use to get the json?

Some useful links i've found,

1)https://blog.chrismitchellonline.com/posts/aws-sqs-message-with-attributes/

2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-send-message.html

Would really appreciate some guidance on this

Answer (score 1):

Can you share the error message that you're receiving. And can you show us an example of `payload` that you're constructing? Basically, the allowable values for `dataType` are found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_MessageAttributeValue.html

Specifically, this part: *"Amazon SQS supports the following logical data types: String, Number, and Binary. For the Number data type, you must use StringValue."*

So when it comes to constructing the value for your key `MessageBody`, you want to use JSON. So the type must be `string` and your value, it has to be valid JSON that's really a string and the inner quotes escaped. So for example, something like this:

```json
"{\"foo\": \"bar\"}"
```

I ran into this same issue while writing unit tests in `goLang` and it works. I know this is 11 months later, but hopefully this helps you or someone else in the future :)